# How i can do this with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3 css codes. I use col-md-4 for blocks, but what i need is ( pagination ) must be always bottom of this blocks.( number of blocks changes ) I tired to use it inside col-md-12 but its still goes up of the page. How i can show pagination on the bottom of those blocks?

```
   <div class="body-content">

   <div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-9 main-content">

  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <ul class="pagination"></ul>
  </div>

 <div class="col-md-3 sidebar"> </div>


 </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: Are you using rows at all?

Comment: row is before col-md-9 , and i cannot take pagination out of col-md-9.

Comment: You should post your full `div` structure including everything up to the `container`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nesting (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting):

```
<div class="body-content">

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-9 main-content">
    <h2>content</h2>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">1</div>
          <div class="col-md-4">2</div>
          <div class="col-md-4">3</div>
          <div class="col-md-4">4</div>
          <div class="col-md-4">5</div>
        </div>
      <ul class="pagination"><li>p1</li></ul>
    </div>  

    <div class="col-md-3 sidebar">Sidebar</div>

</div>
</div>
```